# check if function returns something

Tags: php, function

If the function `validateCustomForm()` returns nothing, then that means all of the variables are set. I tried using `empty()` but I figured since there is something in the function that it will always return false.

**How can I check if a function returns something?**

[Script in action here](http://codepad.org/ogfrZQhD)

```
<?php

function validateCustomForm(){

$os0 = "";
$os1 = "5";
$os2 = "6";
$os3 = "5";
    if(!empty($os0)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $w = "width is missing";
    echo $w;
    }
    if(!empty($os1)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $h = "height is missing";
    echo $h;
    }
    if(!empty($os2)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $c = "color is missing";
    echo $c;
    }
    if(!empty($os3)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $q = "qty is missing";
    echo $q;
    }

    }//end function

$valid = validateCustomForm();

if(!empty($valid)){
echo "something is missing";
} else{
echo "all good";
}


?>
```

Comment: remove the `echo` s, just return a value to be echoed or empty otherwise, or false if you prefer

Comment: I see no `return` statements so `$valid` will always be `void` (`null`)

Comment: when you talk about `return` there has to be a `return`  statement in your function

Comment: quick fix: http://codepad.org/fjUd1oRC

Comment: @Dagon I love it. Wish you would have answered so I could accept your answer.

Comment: @Dagon so I was using empty() correctly?

Comment: not as the function stood, it was fine after being rewritten

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function validateCustomForm(){

    $os0 = "";
    $os1 = "5";
    $os2 = "6";
    $os3 = "5";

    $errors = array();

    if(empty($os0)){
        $errors[] = "width is missing";
    }
    if(empty($os1)){
        $errors[] = "height is missing";
    }
    if(empty($os2)){
        $errors[] = "color is missing";
    }
    if(empty($os3)){
        $errors[] = "qty is missing";
    }
    if(!empty($errors)) {
        return $errors;
    }
    return TRUE;
}//end function

$valid = validateCustomForm();

if($valid !== TRUE){
    echo "something is missing: ";
    echo implode(',' , $valid);
} else{
   echo "all good";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return something in function instead of echo. Like below

```
<?php

function validateCustomForm(){

$os0 = "";
$os1 = "5";
$os2 = "6";
$os3 = "5";
$error = false;
    if(!empty($os0)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $w = "width is missing";
    $error = true;
    }
    if(!empty($os1)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $h = "height is missing";
     $error = true;
    }
    if(!empty($os2)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $c = "color is missing";
     $error = true;
    }
    if(!empty($os3)){
    //do nothing
    }else{
            $q = "qty is missing";
     $error = true;
    }
    return $error;
    }//end function

$valid = validateCustomForm();

if(!empty($valid)){
echo "something is missing";
} else{
echo "all good";
}


?>
```